# How to use indivdual condition in AnyLogic agent based simulation

Tags: conditional-statements, agent, anylogic

I am trying to simulate a customer by using agents. In the statechart I built, I would like to apply to each individual agent the waiting time spent in the system by defining different variables:

WatingTimeStart, WaitingTimeEnd and WaitingTime

In order to assign the waiting time to each agent I am using the following command in the transition prior to the state I would like to apply the condition:

```
this.WaitingTimeStart=time();
```

In the next State I am then using the following:

```
this.WaitingTimeEnd=time();
this.WaitingTime=this.WaitingTimeEnd-this.WaitingTimeStart;
```

Followed by the next transition with the condition (TolerarableWaitingTime is a pre-defined Variable)

```
this.WaitingTime>TolerarableWaitingTime;
```

My Problem is the transition does not accept the condition and is not processing the agents to the next state.

I probably make a mistake in:

- assinging the variable WaitingTime to each agent
- applying the condition correcly

Thanks a lot for any thoughts.

Bastian

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult to understand your question, but here it goes: first, you don't need to use "this", you can just do in the transition previous to the state in question:

```
WaitingTimeStart=time();
```

also by convention your variables should start with a low case letter, so it should be `waitingTimeStart`.

But you don't really even need that code and you are overcomplicating yourself... if you want to apply a waiting time (or a delay) you don't need a conditional transition, you can just use a timeout transition instead, where the timeout time is equal to `TolerarableWaitingTime`

[image: statechart timeout transition]

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you say, my explanation was not the best. I would like to give it a second try. The issue is that i need to combine the timeout with a stocklevel check. furthermore i need to ensure that each agent is measured against its own waiting time.

Comment: so you are saying that the timeout will apply only when the stock is at a certain level? So you can create another transition which is triggered by a message from state to state2, when the stock is at a certain level you send a message with a guard that requires WaitingTime>TolerarableWaitingTime and in the timeout transtion you set a guard that requires the stock to be at a certain level... Check the anylogic help documentation to learn about transition guard (which is an option in the properties of the transition)

Comment: But my answer is correct or not depending on the characteristics of the stock... you need to edit your question and add all these details, otherwise I have to guess and it becomes extremely difficult to help you...